# CSS selector for div while using selenium webdriver and ruby

Tags: html, ruby, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

I have worked on CSS selectors to find an element while using selenium webdriver, but finding the element for below div seems to be difficult.

```
<div class="class1 class2" dd:btnfloatingstyle="top-right" dd:entitytexttype="resultval" id="_78891a36-3d75-432e-9906-760bd918e7cb" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

For finding an element using css selector I usually do:

```
$driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.classname')
```

But I have 2 class names in this case and I don't get the element back while I do:

```
   $driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.class1 class2') or
   $driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.class1 > div.class2') or
   $driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.class1 + div.class2')
```

Am I missing something or is there any other way I can find this element??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try as below:

```
$driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.class1.class2')
```

Just to give a live example, I used the [**Ruby_on_Rails**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) wikipedia link and wrote a code to access the below html table from the link mentioned.

**HTML**

```html
 <table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" align="left">
 <caption>Version history</caption>
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <th class="headerSort" title="Sort ascending">Version</th>
```

**Ruby code**

```ruby
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails"
elem = driver.find_element(:css, 'table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter')
p elem.tag_name
# => "table"
p elem.find_element(:tag_name, 'caption').text
# =>  "Version history"
```